If IV and DV shares a component, can you simplify the linear regression between them?
If y = a - b, x = c - b, for a simple linear regression y ~ x, is it still (c-b) ~ (a-b), or can you simplify it into c ~ a?
Is it even correct to run a regression if you know they share a component?

I think you mean (a-b) ~ (c-b), and a ~ c in the question body

In standard linear regression contexts, anything on the right side of the formula is treated as fixed.
So, "y = a - b, x = c - b" in your original question would be formally treated as modelling the following (where capitals are random variables and lowercase as known/constants):
$$
\begin{aligned}
E[Y]&=\beta_0 + \beta_1 x \\
E[A-b]&=\beta_0 + \beta_1 (c-b) \\
E[A]&=b+\beta_0 + \beta_1 (c-b)
\end{aligned}
$$
So no, the bs do not cancel unless $\beta_1=1$.
Without context, I don't know about "Is it even correct to run a regression if you know they share a component?", but I can't see an issue off the top of my head.
